# Change View head title programmatically

Tags: 8

I have a view of taxonomy terms with exposed filter.
Main view page: site.com/view

I have a text field with 16 different values and urls:

- site.com/view/1
- site.com/view/2
- site.com/view/...
- site.com/view/16

Depending on passed argument I change View title like this:

```
use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
function theme_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) 
{
  
  if( $view->id() == 'MY_VIEW_ID' && $view->current_display === 'VIEW_DISPLAY' && $view->args[0] != 'All')
  {
    $view->setTitle(gamesGenreTitle($view->args[0]));
  }
}

function gamesGenreTitle($val)
{
  $options = options_allowed_values(\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('taxonomy_term')['field_genre']);
  return $options[$val];
}
```

gamesGenreTitle() is getting labels of my field in order to put them to the title.

It works, but it is not changing the head `<title>` tag!

I've tried `theme_preprocess_html(&$variables)` with this code:

```
  $view_id = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('view_id');

  $view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_id);
```

But it only gets the `view id` and I can't access args there in order to change title on only needed pages.

My second guess, which I haven't tried yet, is to validate and explode to array current path, using `\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();`, get the last digit and pass it to `gamesGenreTitle()`.

Or maybe there is better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't necessarily need to access the view object ($view) to get the arguments. You can check all arguments by doing so

```
$params = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameters();
```

Usually you'll find that if you are accesing a view **with contextual filters/parameters** there will be "arg_0, arg_1" parameter keys

```
var_dump($params);
// object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#323 (1) { ["parameters":protected]=> array(4) { ["view_id"]=> string(18) "sample_view" ["display_id"]=> string(6) "page_1" ["arg_0"]=> string(26) "251" } }
```

Then you can do

```
$params = Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('arg_0');
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day! )))